# Remove last character from dictionary<string, dictionary<string, string>> using C#

Tags: c#, linq

I have

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>
```

My inner dictionary has the following data

```
{
  "1": {
    "message-Code1": "   0",
    "msg-Number-Pos11": "0",
    "msg-Number-Pos21": "0",
    "msg-Number-Pos31": " "
  },
  "2": {
    "message-Code2": "   0",
    "msg-Number-Pos12": "0",
    "msg-Number-Pos22": "0",
    "msg-Number-Pos32": " "
  }
```

But I want a out like below

```
{
  "1": {
    "message-Code": "   0",
    "msg-Number-Pos1": "0",
    "msg-Number-Pos2": "0",
    "msg-Number-Pos3": " "
  },
  "2": {
    "message-Code": "   0",
    "msg-Number-Pos1": "0",
    "msg-Number-Pos2": "0",
    "msg-Number-Pos3": " "
  }
```

Last character of the all the `Key`'s is removed i.e `1` in the first set and `2` in the second set of result.

I was trying with below code

```
var result = dictionary.Where(pair => pair.Value.Remove(pair.Value.Key.Last()));
```

This is throwing an error. 
Can anyone help me in bringing the output that I need.

Comment: Dictionary Keys are immutable. Because they are stored/managed based on hashcode of key, so can't change it. But can remove, edit and then add.

Comment: "This is throwing an error" - always, always show the error. Just saying there *is* an error isn't nearly as useful. But you'll need to create new dictionaries instead...

Answer (score 6):

Basically you should create new "inner" dictionaries. That's easy to do though:

```
var replacedOuter = outerDictionary.ToDictionary(
   outerKey => outerKey, // Outer key stays the same
   outerValue => outerValue.ToDictionary(
       innerKey => innerKey.Substring(0, innerKey.Length - 1),
       innerValue => innerValue));
```

Note that if this creates any duplicate keys (i.e. if there were any keys that only differed by final character) an exception will be thrown by the inner `ToDictionary` call.

Answer (score 1):

Since you cant change a dictionary key you would have to re-create the nested dictionary using your new key.

```
foreach (var item in dic.ToArray())
    dic[item.Key] = item.Value.ToDictionary(x => 
                      x.Key.Remove(x.Key.Length - 1), x => x.Value);
```